# Does JavaScripts's .innerHTML grab <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

If you use something like:

```
var contents = document.getElementById('foobar').innerHTML;
```

and `#foobar` contains `<script>` tags, are the `<script>` tags included?

**EDIT:** They are. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/YBzTB/

Comment: Good stated question +1 Buddy

Comment: thats the second question i've seen in the last hour or so that give the exact way to do something, and then asks someone else to do it...  just try it.

Comment: @nathan: But it's a considerable question and taught me something.

Comment: If I was in my IDE pondering this question I would trial and error before Googling this on Bing.

Comment: Lol @nick, you can't google on bing. And also @nathan, i received an answer quicker than I could finish my test on jsfiddle. So it's valid. It's also valid to have a question answered that will prevent someone else from wasting 5 minutes of trial and error.

Comment: @trusktr, i understand the sentiment, but, honestly, i don't know that this would be a waste of 5 minutes for anyone.  i find that learning something for yourself is significantly more useful than having someone else tell you.  i've come to think of stackoverflow as a place to ask questions that i cannot solve myself, as well as a place to answer questions for users that cannot obtain a solution for themselves.

Comment: Indeed, that is true. That is usually how I learn things (trial and error). I was on JSFiddle the second after I posted the question. :D

Comment: @trusktr, haha, Scott Hanselman said "Google it on Bing" in his ASP.NET MVC Basics video on the MVC web site.

Comment: hehe that's funy. "googling" is to internet searching as "kleenex" is to tissues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does:

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/cHdv6/)

```
<div id='foobar'><script type='text/javascript'>alert('kewl');</script></div>

var contents = document.getElementById('foobar').innerHTML;
console.log(contents);
```

Outputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert('kewl');</script>
```